# Java Scanner issues, Notecard class

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a program that is basically virtual notecards. Each notecard has a string for a question and an answer as well as a count for now many times it has been asked. I am using a scanner in many instances and I think i am using it incorrectly, and am not quite sure why. The program will let me answer the first 2 questions, tell me they are incorrect no matter what, and skip letting me answer the last one. Here is the notecard class:

```
public class Notecard {

    public String ans;
    public String q;
    public int count;

    public Notecard(String q, String ans) {
        this.q = q;
        this.ans = ans;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public Boolean answer(String effort) {
        if (this.q.toUpperCase().equals(effort.toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect! Correct answer:" + this.ans);
            count++;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void clearCount() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public String getQ() {
        return this.q;
    }
}
```

and here is my other file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateNotecard {

    int trys;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Get ready to be quizzed \n\n");
        ArrayList<Notecard> notecards = makeCards();
        quiz(notecards);
    }

    static ArrayList<Notecard> makeCards() {
        ArrayList<Notecard> notecards = new ArrayList<Notecard>();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "notecards.txt"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] argg = str.split(",");
                notecards.add(new Notecard(argg[0], argg[1]));
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
        return notecards;
    }

    static void quiz(ArrayList<Notecard> notecards) {
        ArrayList<Notecard> backupList = notecards;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(notecards, new Random(seed));
        int total = notecards.size();
        int correct = 0;
        for (Notecard x : notecards) {
            System.out.println(x.getQ());
            String effort = sc.next();
            Boolean nailedIt = x.answer(effort);
            if (nailedIt) {

                correct++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Notecards: " + total + "\nTotal Correct: "
                + correct);
        System.out.println("Accuracy: " + (correct / total));
        System.out.println("Do you want to repeat? Put \"y\" or \"n\"");
        String choice1 = sc.nextLine();
        if (choice1.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Use only cards missed or all? Type \"missed\" or \"all\"");
            String choice2 = sc.nextLine();
            if (choice2.toUpperCase().equals("MISSED")) {
                quiz(notecards);
            } else {
                quiz(backupList);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

I have a text file which I am using for this program, it contains

```
19-9,10
square root of 4,2
capitol of Missouri,Jefferson City
Blastoise's 1st evolution,squirtle
```

and my output is

```
Get ready to be quizzed 


square root of 4
2
Incorrect! Correct answer:2
capitol of Missouri
Jefferson City
Incorrect! Correct answer:Jefferson City
Blastoise's 1st evolution
Incorrect! Correct answer:squirtle
Total Notecards: 3
Total Correct: 0
Accuracy: 0
Do you want to repeat? Put "y" or "n"
```

Comment: omg thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the wrong things:

```
public Boolean answer(String effort) {
    if (this.q.toUpperCase().equals(effort.toUpperCase())) {
```

Should be

```
    if (this.ans.toUpperCase().equals(effort.toUpperCase())) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Scanner` class is looking for a delimiter to create tokens with, which is by default **whitespace**. Since you enter "2", the `Scanner.next()` finds no delimiters, so no token.

For example, if you enter "Jefferson City", the `Scanner` found one delimiter, so two tokens. `sc.next` in that case would be "Jefferson" only (no "City", that's the next token).

Solution? Read the line from stdin and using `sc.nextLine()`

Comment: Would NextLine be a better choise?

Comment: That's right, I should have clarified. nextLine should solve your issue.